# Keep integers when creating a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm building a program that processes query results returned in JSON. These results can consist in numbers, either float or integers, strings, boolean...

I use `json_normalize` to load the JSON file in a DataFrame. Probably because it can happen that a value is missing (and will be loaded as NaN), integer values are loaded as float: a key/value pair such as `"number": 3` will result in `3.0` in the DataFrame. However, since I don't know where they'll be in the DataFrame, I can't just call `astype` to convert the data type.

Is there some magic trick that will convert numbers to integers wherever applicable (i.e numbers) and necessary (i.e. the data actually contains integers) and ignore any other case (or just keep integers)? For instance:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Strings': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'],
                 'Integers': [1, None,3],
                 'Floats': [13.55, 151.1586, 21.0053]})
```

Integers will contain `1.0, NaN, 3.0`. Instead, I'd like to have `1` and `3`.

I couldn't run `df['Integers'] = df['Integers'].astype('int64')`, and even if I did, I wouldn't in reality know what columns actually contain integers. I would be hitting `ValueError` or `IntCastingNaNError` exceptions is all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to do it?

You can use `pd.Int64Dtype` to have the column with `NaN` as integers, Pandas will use `<NA>` to represent `NaN` for integers.

```py
>>> df['Integers'].astype(pd.Int64Dtype())
0       1
1    <NA>
2       3
Name: Integers, dtype: Int64
```

Comment: OK, I guess I'll need to go through all columns and catch exceptions, but that does work. Thanks!

Comment: But `pd.isna()` will identify them as `NaN`, so you don'tneed to catch the exception.

Answer (score 1):

To convert all numeric columns to integer, regardless of whether they contain NaN:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
'''
Convert all numeric columns in a dataframe to integer.
'''

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Strings': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'],
        'Integers': [1, None, 3],
        'MoreIntegers': [2, 4, 6],
        'Floats': [13.55, 151.1586, 21.0053],
        'MoreFloats': [1.3, 2.4, None]
    }
)
# Create list of numeric types
types = ['float64', 'int64', 'Int64']
# Create dictionary of all column names and dtypes
all_col = df.dtypes.apply(lambda x: x.name).to_dict()
# Create dictionary of numeric column names and dtypes
num_col = {
    k: v for k, v in all_col.items() if v in types
}
for k, v in num_col.items():
    # Convert integer columns, with or without NaN
    if v in ['int64', 'Int64']:
        df[k] = df[k].astype(dtype='Int64')
    if v in ['float64']:
        if df[k].isnull().values.any():
            # Convert float columns, with NaN
            df[k] = df[k]\
                .apply(lambda x: x if np.isnan(x) else np.int64(x))\
                .astype(dtype='Int64')
        else:
            # Convert float columns, without NaN
            df[k] = df[k]\
                .astype(dtype={k: 'int64'})\
                .astype(dtype={k: 'Int64'})
print(df)
print()
print(df.dtypes)
>>>  Strings  Integers  MoreIntegers  Floats  MoreFloats
>>> 0     abc         1             2      13           1
>>> 1     def      <NA>             4     151           2
>>> 2     ghi         3             6      21        <NA>
>>> 
>>> Strings         object
>>> Integers         Int64
>>> MoreIntegers     Int64
>>> Floats           Int64
>>> MoreFloats       Int64
>>> dtype: object
```